# AngularJS Firebase sendEmailVerification not working

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to send a verification email to the registering user using Firebase.

My registration controller is like the following:

```
app.controller("MyregisterCtrl", ["$scope", "firebase", "$firebaseAuth", "$location", function ($scope, firebase, $firebaseAuth, $location) {

    $scope.signUp = function () {
        var username = $scope.user.email;
        var password = $scope.user.password;


        if (username && password) {
            var auth = $firebaseAuth();
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

            auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
            user.sendEmailVerification()
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("User signup success");
                    $scope.errMsg = false;
                    $location.path('/login.signin');
                }).catch(function (error) {
                $scope.errMsg = true;
                $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
            });
        }
    }

}]);
```

The user gets registered in the Firebase user database. But I have to click three times in a row on the submit button in order to get a verification email. Very strange.

Why doesn't it send it on the first submit click?

Here is the error screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a user account is an operation that can take some time. If you call `sendEmailVerification()` before the operation is completed, you'll get the error message in your screenshot (for any future questions: don't post pictures of text please, post the actual text itself).

To solve the problem, you can wait until the account is created by waiting for the so-called promise to resolve:

```
auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
    .then(function(user) {
        user.sendEmailVerification()
    }).then(function () {
        console.log("User signup success");
        $scope.errMsg = false;
        $location.path('/login.signin');
    }).catch(function (error) {
        $scope.errMsg = true;
        $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
    });
```

So the sequence here:

1. create the user account
2. once this succeeds, send a verification email
3. once this succeeds, log success and redirect
4. if either 1 or 2 fails, show an error message